# IF....THEN statement in T-SQL to perform UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> Disclaimer: I am still learning SQL so I apologize if my question comes off as amateur-ish or is otherwise a very simple answer. I have no formal training. I am teaching myself. Thanks.

A particular query was created to update the EMAIL column with data in the EMAIL2 column should the EMAIL column be blank. This query goes on to grab data from the EMAIL3-6 columns should any prior ones also be blank in an attempt to populate the EMAIL column. It currently sits as follows:

`update Parents
  set email = email2
  where email = ' ' OR email is null
  go`

`update Parents
  set email = email3
  where email = ' ' OR email is null
  go`

`update Parents
  set email = email6 
  where email = ' ' OR email is null
  go`

(and so on)

Is there a more simple way, using some sort of IF...THEN type conditions to check for blank or null in the EMAIL column and populate it based on data in the secondary column(s)? These columns would also need to be checked for blank or null values and skipped if blank or null is true.

I appreciate any advice that can be given. The above query works it just doesn't feel like the best way to go about doing it.

Comment: Why has nobody pointed out that having columns Email1-Email6 is a bad idea in the first place? Have a separate table with `ParentID,Email` and multiple rows to allow for multiple emails. Read up on [First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: +1 for suggesting normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A handy function you will want to become aquainted with is [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx). It allows you to simplify your logic in cases where you might like to treat a value like a NULL. For example, if an application was putting a sentinel value of 'NA' in a NULLable column `column1`, `NULLIF(column1, 'NA')` would return the NULL value for all the NULLs and all the NAs. In your case, we'd use this trick to convert empty strings into NULLs.

The other thing we'll do is trim all the empty strings down so our NULLIF only needs to check for the scenario of '' (instead of '', ' ', '  ', ad nauseum). TSQL only provides LTRIM and [RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) and I have a habit of using `RTRIM` although trimming an empty string from either direction will result in our desired state. `NULLIF(RTRIM(column1),'')`

Using that expression, we will now have the right thing to plug into the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function. Thus

```
UPDATE
    P
SET
    email = COALESCE(NULLIF(RTRIM(P.email2), ''), NULLIF(RTRIM(P.email3), ''), NULLIF(RTRIM(P.email4), ''))
FROM
    dbo.Parents P
WHERE
    -- This will force a table scan which can be a bad thing for performance
    -- Generally, one should avoid wrapping functions around a column and instead
    -- apply them to the thing being tested
    NULLIF(RTRIM(P.email), '') IS NULL
```

Comment: wow. I honestly didn't expect to get any answers so soon, let alone helpful ones. I truly appreciate all the info you guys have given me and I have some reading to do. As a side note, for the specific purpose performance isn't an issue. What we do is move data from one database to another but first we do some cleanup (such as populating the fields relative to the new database). Currently, most of this is done in ACCESS. However, I find SQL Server easier to work with, especially since the end result is in SQL Server. Though I'm certainly no expert, I'm trying to streamline the tedious process.

Comment: I would like to point out that the RTRIM is not needed.  The NULLIF function doesn't care about the difference between ' ', '    ', and ' '.  Take a look at my example below to see the example I was working up before you posted.  GREAT ANSWER! +1 for NULLIF.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
update Parents 
      set email = COALESCE(
                    NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(email2), '')),
                    NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(email3), '')),
                    NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(email4), '')),
                    NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(email5), '')),
                    NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(email6), ''))
                  ) 
where email = ' ' OR email is null
```

The

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(email2)
```

will make sure the convert ' ' to an empty string '', since SQL Server has no trim, but two separate functions `LTRIM` and `RTRIM`. NULLIF returns null if the two expressions are equal.
So if any of the email cols is null or just ' ' it will return null.

The `COALESCE` function will return the value of the first expression, that is not `null`.

Comment: -1, Not really, for example, in case that `email2` is `' '`, then it will take that value as the email, not `email3` as intended.

Comment: This would work if you wrapped each email with `NULLIF(TRIM(email#), '')` to catch `' '` by converting it to a blank `''` with `TRIM`, then `null` with `NULLIF`.

Comment: @mellamokb SQL Server doesn't have the `TRIM` function, I think, but your logic still aplies

Comment: @Lamak: Ah, ya could use either `LTRIM` or `RTRIM` instead since it's blank.  Working demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e378a/2.

Comment: Don't need both LTRIM and RTRIM, since if it's just blank spaces, either one will trim it to an empty string.

Comment: +1 Answer is good now, however, it would be good to add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Not to make this a tutorial on COALESCE and NULLIF but to proof everything @billinkc provided in his answer, this is why that works.  (Sorry I was working on the solution as he answered it).  Plop this into SSMS and have a look at the results.  A simple update like shown above will do nicely though.

Just Discovered the SQL Fiddle Resource:
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bd7d/5/0)

```
--Setup the temp table
DECLARE @Parents TABLE (
    ParentsId INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    email varchar(max),
    email2 varchar(max),
    email3 varchar(max),
    email4 varchar(max),
    email5 varchar(max),
    email6 varchar(max)
)

--This would be the pull from your real Parents Table.
INSERT INTO @Parents 
SELECT
    NULL,'test@domain.com',' ',NULL,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL,'   ',NULL,NULL,NULL,'test2@domain.com'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL,'',NULL,NULL,NULL,'test3@domain.com'

--Look at the data before we cleanse it
SELECT * FROM @Parents

--Take a look at what COALESCE looks like before the cleanse
SELECT ParentsId, COALESCE(email2,email3,email4,email5,email6) AS NewEmail FROM @Parents

--RUN the NULLIF
UPDATE @Parents SET 
    email2 = NULLIF(email2,' '),
    email3 = NULLIF(email3,' '),
    email4 = NULLIF(email4,' '),
    email5 = NULLIF(email5,' '),
    email6 = NULLIF(email6,' ')

SELECT * FROM @Parents

--Take a look at what COALESCE looks like after the cleanse
SELECT ParentsId, COALESCE(email2,email3,email4,email5,email6) AS NewEmail FROM @Parents
```